# Android Studio how to use Request in Fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, request, httprequest

I want to make this request in a fragment but the errors, as could I do?, thanks! I have many errors as .`Builder()` or `OkHttpClient()` when I want to implement it in a Fragment so I do not say any error in particular

```
 String url = "https://freegeoip.net/json/"
    Request mRequest = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
    Context mContext // A UI context
    new OkHttpClient().newCall(mRequest).enqueue(new Callback() {
        Handler mainHandler = new Handler(mContext.getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
            String responseBody = null;
            try {
                responseBody = response.body().string();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // handle error
                    }
                });
            }

            final String finalResponseBody = responseBody;
            mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // handle response body
                    try {
                        JSONObject locationObject = new JSONObject(finalResponseBody);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e) {
            mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mNetworkListener.onNetworkError(e.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: have you working request code in you activity?

Comment: i don't think so

Comment: then may be you don't have proper setup for OkHttpClient.

Comment: and how can i put the proper setup for OkHttpClient?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-OkHttp/article.html